# The name provided is not a properly formed account name

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssas, ssis-2012, ssas-2012

[SSAS errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaHQW.png)

im getting these errors when i run the my SSAS project, anyone know about this?

Comment: No, but my first guess is that you haven't entered a valid account name for the login used by SSAS to query the relational database when processing.

Comment: I have used windows authentication for SSAS, and set my windows user name and password, but i haven't added password for windows login then i keep that space as blank, only set username. Does SSAS must require password when we use windows authentication? @TabAlleman

Comment: No idea, I'm not an expert on login security stuff.

Comment: i fixed the problem, that because i haven't used the SQL Server Authentication, when i change the Authentication, it process successfully. @TabAlleman

Comment: Anyway, @TabAlleman thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, that because i haven't used the SQL Server Authentication, when i change the Authentication, it process successfully.